# UPDATE doesn't know where to update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to update a database. I can connect perfectly. my problem comes when I try to update for a certain user (the one that's using the website). when I tell the code the persons id it will update in the correct place. such as...

```
$id = '1';
```

however when I do this

```
$id = "select id from users where fname=$fname and lname=$lname";
```

nothing happens and no error message appears. this is sending me nuts as I just don't know wy it won't work. the whole code is here to see if anyone may know why this isn't working. thank you anyone for any tips.

```
<body>
    <h1 id="title"> Quiz </h1>
    <?php
        session_start();

        $connection = mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a4987634_quiz", "***********")
        or die (mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("a4987634_quiz", $connection)
        or die (mysql_error());

        $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
        $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
        $id = "select id from users where fname='matthew' and lname='briant'";

        $answer = $_POST['answer'];

        if(isset($_POST['answer']) &&
        $_POST['answer'] == 'public enemy')
        {
    ?>
    <h3 id = "correct"> Correct </h3>
    <?php

        $sqlcorrect = "UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE id = $id";

        mysql_query($sqlcorrect);
        (mysql_error());

        }
        else {
    ?>
    <h3 id = "incorrect"> Incorrect </h3>
    <?php

        $sqlwrong = "UPDATE users SET q1 = 'wrong' WHERE id = $id";
        mysql_query($sqlwrong);
        (mysql_error());

        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I even get the fname and lname to appear so I don't understand how this isn't working.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: i had no idea these were out of date. thanks i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

> ...however when i do this

```
$id = "select id from users where fname=$fname and lname=$lname";
```

You do realize that this does nothing, but assign a string to a variable, do you?

You have to

- run the query `$result = mysql_query("SELECT whatever FROM wherever")`
- fetch the results `mysql_fetch_row($result)`
- use it in your update query

Or, even better, you could formulate a better UPDATE script:

```
$updateSQL = "UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE lname=$lname and fname=$fname";
```

Running this single command will allow to set the q1 to 'correct' for all users with the specified name attributes.

Comment: thanks. i'll try it. i'm new and really just testing to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Id = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select id from users where fname='matthew' and lname='briant'"));
$id=$Id['id];
```

replace like this

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "select id from users where fname='matthew' and lname='briant'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$id = $row['id'];

$sqlcorrect = "UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE id = ".$id;
//or 
//subquery
$sqlcorrect = "UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE id = (select id from users where fname='matthew' and lname='briant');
//use 'in' if subquery return more than one result
$sqlcorrect = "UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE id in (select id from users where fname='matthew' and lname='briant');
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for. i don't know how you do it. thanks a load. hopefully this will work.

Comment: @Pragnesh why do you use a subquery? That is very slow! This is **exaclty** what the WHERE statement is for! And that way it does not matter if there is 1 or several results to be updated!

`UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE fname='matthew' and lname='briant'`

Comment: @ppeterka, because i think user is look for this as he is assigning string to `$id` and try `"UPDATE users SET q1 = 'correct' WHERE id = ".$id;`

Comment: when i try it this is the error message. Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a4987634/public_html/q15.php on line 80

Comment: @Pragnesh the OP is inexperienced regarding SQL. If you can help big with the same effort, don't help small! Given his table structure, the two queries do exactly the same, but the one I suggested is quicker, and a lot easier to read.